# Inference on joint Poisson and Binomial observations

Tags: probability, distributions, bayesian, estimation, inference

Pick a positive integer $N$. I want to know $N$, but you won't tell me. Instead, you tell me four things:

1. Draw a random number $n_{p}$ from a Poisson distribution defined by its expected value $\lambda = hN$; tell me $n_{p}$.
2. Draw a random number $n_{b}$ from a Binomial distribution defined by $N$ trials and probability $p$ of success in each trial; tell me $n_{b}$.
3. Tell me $h$ (which is a positive real number)
4. Tell me $p$ (which is a positive real number less than $1$)

I want to infer $N$. How should I do so?

In my ignorance, I tried picking an $N$ which maximizes the product:

$\left(\frac{(hN)^{n_{p}}\exp^{-hN}}{n_{p}!}\right)\left(\frac{N!}{n_{b}!(N-n_{b})!}p^{n_{b}}(1-p)^{N-n_{b}}\right)$

Unfortunately, this seems to systematically underestimate $N$. I assume there's a 'right' way to do this. Please teach me!

Here's simple code that maximizes that likelihood. Note that it systematically underestimates $N$. I'd love it if there were a "standard" way to estimate $N$ that was unbiased.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import numpy as np
from numpy import log as ln
from scipy.special import gammaln

N_true = 50 # To be inferred
p = 0.90 # Binomial probability of success per trial
h = 3.9 # Scale factor for Poisson distribution
N_inferred = []
for trial in range(10000):
    n_p = np.random.poisson(h*N_true)
    n_b = np.random.binomial(N_true, p)

    def poisson_neg_log_likelihood(N):
        return -(n_p*ln(h*N) + -h*N - gammaln(1 + n_p))

    def binomial_neg_log_likelihood(N):
        return -(gammaln(1+N) - gammaln(1+n_b) - gammaln(1+N-n_b) +
                 n_b*ln(p) + (N-n_b)*ln(1-p))

    N_candidates = np.arange(max(n_b, 1), 2*(1+n_b)/(1-p))
    nlls = (poisson_neg_log_likelihood(N_candidates) +
            binomial_neg_log_likelihood(N_candidates))
    N_inferred.append(N_candidates[nlls.argmin()])
average_inference = np.mean(N_inferred)
print("My average inference for N is:", average_inference)
if average_inference < N_true:
    print("(which unfortunately, is less than", N_true, "...)")
```

Comment: should this have the self-study tag? https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: No, it should not.

Answer (score 1):

Your goal of maximizing 
$$
L(N) = \left(\frac{(hN)^{n_{p}}\exp^{-hN}}{n_{p}!}\right)\left(\frac{N!}{n_{b}!(N-n_{b})!}p^{n_{b}}(1-p)^{N-n_{b}}\right)
$$
over $N$ corresponds to finding the maximum likelihood estimator of $N$. I would consider this a "right" approach, however the parameter space is a subset of the integers which makes the problem slightly nonstandard.

If the second derivative of $L$ is negative, you could solve the inequality
$$
L(N) > L(N-1).
$$
If you solved for $N$, you would get something like $N < c$, so your MLE of $N$, call it $\hat{N}$ would be the greatest integer not exceeding this $c$. You could use the estimator $\hat{N} - E[\hat{N}]$ if you wanted to remove the bias.

Comment: Using code is fine; the part I'm disappointed by is that the $N$ I infer by this method typically underestimates the true $N$. See the code I added to the question.

Comment: @Andrew yeah this is an interesting problem. MLEs are typically asymptotically very nicely distributed. However, you can't jut let $N \to \infty$ because this is what you're trying to estimate. Though, if you can approximate or calculate $E[\hat{N}]$ then you're good as far as de-biasing it goes.